# Help with the Android Cursor

Tags: android, cursor

So I have a Cursor that is getting a result from a query to the application database. I know that there is at least one correct entry in the database since I was able to retrieve the string from the row previously.

I then changed some of the logic to accommodate the result and am suddenly getting null returned when calling c.getString(0). The relevant code is posted below.

I'm new to Android and Java, so I might be missing some subtlety that's causing the problem.

```
   Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(tempJobName.build(), 
           null, null, null, null);

   for (c.moveToFirst(); c.isAfterLast() == false; c.moveToNext())
   {
       Log.w(TAG, c.getString(0));
       if (c.getString(0).equalsIgnoreCase(jobName))
       {
           existed = true;
           break;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code from before when you had it working?  I'd like to see if it was something simple in the changes you made.

Comment: I wish I could. D: I hadn't committed the working code since it wasn't intended to be a final part of the project, so my changes are gone.

Comment: Which IDE? Most IDE Store local history. If you are using elicpse Team --> Show Local History will keep a change log.

Comment: Where is the Team menu? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add more details. But since you did find some records, the solution for your problem is easy. Could you please replace this line with this? ( First column of table might change right :))

```
c.getString(0);
```

with

```
int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME);// You could also use getcolumnIndexorThrow variant.
c.getString(columnIndex);
```

if this does not work, then your table does not have the column. You are simply barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Yup, something went wrong with my database. Thanks for the help. I'm going to delete it and try again.